# Unique DVD info?

Tags: disk, dvd, identification

I was wondering, is there some type of disc ID i can use to search in my database to see if that disc is has been scanned or not? All disc were created by me typically burnt on windows.

-edit- I could compare write time and volume label to see if the disc has been scanned but i notice if i put in certain commercial disc that fields are blank or wrong causing many false positives (i once had the time set to the future, i dont know if people want to archive the contents of files on a commercial disc in my app).

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This is a perfectly reasonable question!

Comment: Not really programming related, but never the less interesting  :)

Comment: Not programming related but i think there is no need to close this question.

Comment: I'd like to programatically convenience the user of my apps by notifying them that the disc has been indeed scanned and not have them wait minutes or many minutes to find out (it depend on amount of files, there could be thousands).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look at
http://wiki.dvdlookup.org/index.php?title=Disc_Identification

Comment: It looks like volumename + time are the only ways to do it(?). Excluding hashing which will take a long time (thats the reason why i want an id)

Comment: Thanks for the info, now i know what i need to do >:D